Blazor web app couldn't find js function in external js file
Here is my repo with fresh template reproducing the issue.
On the counter page in the button click handler added JS interop call which should normally invoke js function named "sayHello()" locatedn in wwwroot/JSFile.js
https://github.com/konst-sh/JSFunctionNotFound/tree/master
I keep getting this error in browser console:
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'sayHello' ('sayHello' was undefined).
The script reference seem to be located properly in App.razor file inside the  tag:
<script src="JSFile.js"></script>

if same function is added to the Counter.razor page inside the script tag it works as expected
<script>
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello from JSFile");
}
</script>


You can remove export in  JSFile.js ,I  remove it and it works well like this:

If you want use export ,you should use JSHost.ImportAsync,you can learn more from this website:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/import-export-interop?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Wow, thank you so much. Why isn't that mentioned anywhere in the documentation...

This is javascript knowledge point  , so the tutorials of asp.net core do not mention  .

As you mentioned it cannot find the file which means it cannot find the path or not set to the correct path in some sort of project setting.
I recommend to use C# code like Directory (System.IO.Directory) class to locate the exact path in static root directory (wwwroot) and put in some variable or directly call in in code.
Something like this (it's a razor engine page code compatible with your code)
@{
    string jsfilePath = $"{System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")}/JSFile.js";

}
<script src=@jsfilePath></script>

I'm not sure about  /JSFile.js or //JSFile.js path.

Hi, sorry I just noticed I've somehow didn't commited actual project to repo. Now its all there. The script file wwwroot/JSFile.js is included in Components/App.razor  in the 
Also in ms docs for the case when the script file is external file they claim it only need to be placed in wwwroot and the relative path will be just file name:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/location-of-javascript?view=aspnetcore-8.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js
